# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. error Failed to install the app

Tags: react-native

I get this error when trying to start react-native app.
I have path to ANDROID_HOME, JAVA_HOME, platform-tools. I use android studio emulator.

[My error mesage in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3Byq.png)

Be free to ask me any questions.
Thanks for any help

EDIT1: For starting I use `npx react-native run-android`, when I use ract-native-cli, it shows the same error.

Comment: What happens if you try `react-native run-android` ?

Comment: usually its not necesarry but try add cli dependencies to your package.json https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/995#issuecomment-617064685

Comment: I read that react-native-cli  couses other problem so I use `npx react-native run-android` (I dont use react-native-cli)

Comment: I tried it with cli and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you connected any device? ( any adb devices ? )

Comment: It turns on my android studio emulator, but then shows this error